# CakePHP 2:3 : How can I add fadeIn delay time in cakephp.

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have tried this effect by cakephp js helper,it's working fine.Here I have tried several ways to add fadeIn delay time,but I have field.

```
$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn');
```

How can I add fadeIn delay time in this effect ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to create basic effects of javascript or jquery using cakephp is you may use this

```
JsHelper::effect($name, $options = array());
```

Example would be.

```
$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn', array('speed' => 'slow');
```

But I would suggest just code your script in plain Javascript/Jquery because it's more flexible than using the built-in JsHelper in cakephp due to limited functions and it's easy to use. Just include your script in your View.

Example using JQuery:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('your_script_name'); ?>
```

and in your  your_script_name.js

```
$('#sending').delay(slow).fadeIn(1000);
```

Hope I have helped you man.

Comment: How can I add delay time in array parameter ?  array('speed' => 'slow') have there like array('delay' => '5000') ?

Comment: You can refer here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::effect please read the cookbook thoroughly. About delay time. I suggest cake JSHelper per reading the JsHelper. Why not just make a native JQuery script?

Answer (score 0):

Cf docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper::effect
You have an array "$options" with a "speed" key